# how to install perl Inline::Java

Tags: perl, inline

From Inline-0.44, it says how to install the default C like below. But I can't find instruction to install Inline::Java , can someone shine some light?

To install Inline do this:

```
perl Makefile.PL;
make;
make test;
make install;
```

Comment: `Inline` v0.44 is pretty ancient (as these things go).

Comment: I see Inline-0.53 but still nowhere shows how to install Inline::Java . thanks

Comment: `cpan Inline::Java`, unless your `cpan` command is very ancient too.

Comment: Ok, I had to use the version 0.53 . thanks a lot. I am new to this stuff, just heard of it yesterday. Very surprised that this is not documented anywhere in the cpan site. Even if it does, its not clear to a new user like me.

Comment: It's documented in the material included with perl itself. `perldoc cpan` or just `man cpan`.

Answer (score 2):

On ubuntu/debian you can search for the module using 
 apt-cache search Inline::Java
Then install the module using
 apt-get install libinline-java-perl

Answer (score 1):

[Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/~etj/Inline-Java-0.58/) installation from CPAN doesn't work on RHEL/Cent OS. You need to get the tar.gz of the package and then install manually. Make sure you pass J2SDK path in Makefile.PL.

perl Makefile.PL J2SDK="Java path"

**e.g.**  perl Makefile.PL J2SDK=/usr/

Check [README](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ETJ/Inline-Java-0.58/README) for more details.